# Proving $\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4}{n }\sin^{3}(\frac{2\pi nx}{3})dx=\pi $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Proving

> $$
> \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty }{4 \over n}\,
> \sin^{3}\left(\, 2\pi nx \over 3\,\right)\,{\rm d} x\ =\ \pi
> $$

Comment: Is this post supposed to be visible from outer space ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Interchange sum and integral; use $2i\sin(x)=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$; expand, manipulate and integrate. You'll obtain terms like $\zeta(2)/\pi$. Add them.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\int_0^1 \sin^3\left(\dfrac{2n \pi x}3\right)dx = \dfrac{9}{8 \pi n}\left(1-\cos\left(\dfrac{2n \pi}3\right) \right) = \dfrac{9}{4 \pi n} \sin^2\left(\dfrac{n\pi}3\right)$$
Hence, the summation is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac4n \dfrac9{4 \pi n} \sin^2\left(\dfrac{n\pi}3\right) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac9{\pi n^2}\sin^2\left(\dfrac{n \pi}3\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac9{\pi n^2}\cdot\dfrac34 - \sum_{n=3,6,\ldots}^{\infty} \dfrac9{\pi n^2} \dfrac34 = \pi$$
where we used the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the following identity:
$$ \sin(3\theta)=-4\sin^3(\theta)+3\sin(\theta) $$
to get
$$ \sin^3(\theta)=\frac{3}{4}\sin(\theta)-\frac14\sin(3\theta). $$
You can easily get the answer.